# How to get "7kb runtime"?

Tags: lightning-web-components

The home page of lwc lists "Lean, 7kb runtime optimized for performance, with minimal boilerplate code" as one of the selling points. Using just the following commands:

```
$ npx lwc-create-app my-app
$ cd my-app
$ yarn
$ yarn build
```

Results in a couple of JS files, the one containing the framework (1.app.js) looks to be 86k. Are there some build settings I need to get that smaller?

Comment: I am not completely sure how you can measure that but you are looking at the generated code whereas the 7kb refers to *runtime* optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ~7kb refers to the engine standalone minified and gzipped without any polyfills for browser compatibility (IE11 and friends).

For example on our doc site on https://lwc.dev, you can open dev tools and see the raw engine URL (in UMD format): https://lwc.dev/assets/js/lwc/engine_v100.js (this one is bigger because it contains the synthetic shadow DOM polyfills.

Not sure if lwc-create-app has a PROD mode where it does the minification, but if not you should file a bug.

If you are using tools like webpack or rollupjs, normally these tools bundle in chunks depending on internal heuristics, which is normally a fine approach, but depending on the use case, sometimes you just want to separate the engine by itself to make the cache-ability better.

We will be open sourcing soon a bunch of sample apps and projects so you can see some examples on how to do it. We will add the links into the communities section on the LWC official docs (lwc.dev)

All that being said we will check the number with the latest version and triple-check the size is accurate.

Comment: The build command runs `lwc-services build -m production`, so that is the minified version. Is there a way to edit the compile targets? i.e., omit polyfills for browsers we don't support?

Comment: To add to the answer from @Diego the size is dependent on the webpack build. Having said that I released yesterday a newer version of `lwc-services` which separates the engine from other dependencies.Check out [version 1.2.0] (https://github.com/muenzpraeger/lwc-create-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2019-06-05). `0.app.js` is the bundle with the engine some some dependency that the webpack heuristics added. It's also "live" on [this site](https://lwc-recipes-oss.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: The default config for the LWC compiler that is set in `lwc-services` excludes older browsers, see [here](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/lwc-create-app/blob/5cec91ece621fd8d415e3d96a7c82db81fe4ef12/packages/lwc-services/example/lwc-services.config.js#L42).